# Automatically redeploy a GCP cloud function based on git tag

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I have a GCP function, I used to managed it via Terraform cloud and the git SHA.  Changing it each time, plan and apply.

I hoped that changing to tag_name from commit_sha would cause the gcp function to be redeployed on re-creation of a specific tag.

It does trigger cloud build to rebuild the code but not a redeployment.

What should we change in order to trigger the redeployment.

```
  build_config {
    runtime     = var.xxx_runtime
    entry_point = var.xxx_entry_point
    source {
      repo_source {
        project_id   = var.project
        repo_name    = var.xxx_repo_name
        tag_name     = var.xxx_tag_name
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is the tag new? Or did you overwrite existing tags and try to redeploy the new files over the same tag?

Comment: If i want to re-deploy i delete and recreate the same tag

Answer (score 1):

Terraform keeps a state of what it did. If it deployed a component (functions cloud run,...) with a version named ABC, it stores it in the state.

Next time, if you ask to deploy the version ABC, Terraform will first check the state and evaluate what it has to do. In that case, nothing, ABC is already deployed!

And terraform won't check if the files are the same or not. Only the version in the state!

To solve that, you must either rename your version (or tag) or delete first the function to clean the state and then deploy it again.